# Преобразование даты в определенный формат

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, дата, jstl

Добрый день! На странице jsp с помощью библиотеки **fmt** преобразовываю дату в формат: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm, используя пользовательский тег. Знаю, что его не за чем тут использовать, но так сказали. Но вылетает исключение:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "${date}" to class     "java.util.Date" for attribute "value": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager at     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
```

Подробный стектрейс, я думаю, не имеет смысла выкладывать.

**Вот как я преобразовываю в tag-file:**

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ attribute name="date"  rtexprvalue="true" type="java.util.Date" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatDate value='${date}' type="both" pattern='yyyy-MM-dd'/>
```

**И вывожу в свою страницу jsp:**

```
<em:fullDate date="${reception.arrivalDate}"/>
```

Поле arrivalDate имеет тип Date.

Собственно вопрос, как вывести дату в определенном формате в пользовательском тег-файле?

Не может преобразовать значение в этой строчке:

```
<fmt:formatDate value='${date}' type="both" pattern='yyyy-MM-dd'/>
```

Отдебажил тег-файл, в date заноситься дата, вроде бы все правильно, не могу понять в чем дело.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без пользовательских тегов все работает, т.е. если просто взять либу fmt и сразу значение преобразовывать в jsp.

Файл библиотеки тегов em.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jsee/web-jsptagLibrary_2_0.xsd" version="1.0">
<tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>em</short-name>
<uri>/WEB-INF/errortaglib.tld</uri>

<tag>
    <name>message</name>
    <tag-class>ua.nure.martseniuk.SummaryTask4.web.ErrorOutTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    <attribute> 
        <name>key</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute> 
    <attribute> 
        <name>map</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute> 
</tag>

<tag-file>
    <name>birthDate</name>
    <path>/WEB-INF/tags/userBirthDate.tag</path>
</tag-file>

<tag-file>
    <name>fullDate</name>
    <path>/WEB-INF/tags/userFullDate.tag</path>
</tag-file>
```

Буду рад любому совету!

Comment: Выводить данные нужно поидее так: `<fmt:formatDate value="${reception.arrivalDate}" type="both" pattern='yyyy-MM-dd'/>`, можете добавить пример jsp страницы, на которой можно воспроизвести вашу ошибку?

Comment: да, вы правы. Если выводить так на jsp, то все получиться, но проблема в том, что нужно использовать пользовательские теги для вывода на jsp, и когда я это делаю - то вылетает ошибка конвертации

Comment: приложи полный листинг кастомного taglib.tld

Comment: вопрос дополнен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не разобрался как работает файл .tld (не смог найти версию библиотеки с поддержкой tag-file). Есть рабочий вариант похожий на ваш. Содержимое файла .jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="em" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>    
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />
<em:fullDate date='${now}'/>
```

Содержимое файла /WEB-INF/tags/fullDate.tag

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ attribute name="date"  rtexprvalue="true" type="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:formatDate value='${date}' type="both" pattern='yyyy-MM-dd'/>
```